# Angular - Justifying and changing text size depending on div size - No JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an Angular app and I am displaying different strings on top of one another within a `<div>`, however I am wanting them to be justified to the width of the div.

1. Shorter strings should have larger font-size in order to fill the space, not simply adding white space between the letters.
2. Long strings should have smaller font size & **should not** wrap onto the next line.

This is a visual representation of what I am after:
[image]

I have seen [this link](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/) showing different methods of doing something like this, but I just cannot get it to work...

*Forgot to add code. Here you go.*

**component.ts**

```
export class FitTextComponent implements OnInit {
  line1 = 'this is text for line 1';
  line2 = 'less text';
  line3 = 'medium amount of text';
  line4 = 'this will be a really long line';

  text = [this.line1, this.line2, this.line3, this.line4];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <p *ngFor="let line of text">{{line}}</p>
</div>
```

**component.css**

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
```

**[Here is a stackblitz to play with](https://stackblitz.com/edit/justfy-text-size)**

Comment: Very difficult to help you without seeing your code, what exactly you've tried, and what isn't working.

Comment: @sol - Added now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have left this as a comment, but I need 50 reputation apparently...

I would recommend looking at [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container).

They reference the link you mentioned, but also address other solutions like: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

They also discuss specific solutions to adjusting the size dependent on if it is modifying based on the body or a container.

I would take a look. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: It seems that a lot of the answers/fiddles deal with the scaling upon changing window size, but not the extra requirement of wanting text-size being bigger to fill the width (ie: http://jsfiddle.net/0tpvccjt/1009/)

Comment: They mention setting font size to 100%. Doing that with their solutions should scale the text with the window size. https://jsfiddle.net/T84wL/3/

Comment: This is also a good working example of what you're looking for: https://codepen.io/maciejkorsan/pen/BWLryj with a different implementation.

Comment: Do you know if there is a version available for Angular?

Comment: I believe you can use this, you just have to do an extra step. See: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af under the section "how to use a library that does not have type (.d.ts)".